# Query builder in Doctrine_Table?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I have a previously writen query in other Doctrine project using Query Builder.

```
$qb->select('c', 'm')
           ->from('Chapter c')
           ->leftJoin('c.Book m')
           ->orderBy('c.chapterno DESC')
           ->addOrderBy('m.id ASC')
           ->groupBy('m.id')
           ->where('c.chapterno = (SELECT MAX(v.chapterno) FROM Chapter v WHERE v.mid = m.id)')
           ->limit($max);
```

How can I replicate this in my inherited class from Doctrine_table in symfony?

I am using symfony 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://prendreuncafe.com/blog/post/Optimize-your-Doctrine-Workflow-with-Specialized-Queries) is a nice solution to organize your queries:

Answer (score 1):

In your `ChapterTable` class, something like the following:

```
public function getChapters($max)
{
    $qry = self::getInstance()
        ->createQuery("c")
        ->leftJoin('c.Book m')
        ->orderBy('c.chapterno DESC')
        ->addOrderBy('m.id ASC')
        ->groupBy('m.id')
        ->where('c.chapterno = (SELECT MAX(v.chapterno) FROM Chapter v WHERE v.mid = m.id)')
        ->limit($max);

    return $qry->execute();
}
```

Then you can call this with eg:

```
$myMaxValue = 25;
$results = Doctrine::getTable("Chapter")->getChapters($myMaxValue);
```